# How to backup Viber chat messages to Gmail automatically?

Tags: backup, gmail, automation, viber-messenger

I see that Viber app has the feature of backing up messages and send emails.
I want to do that automatically so as all my Viber messages are safely backed up.
How can I do that with Viber app?

Comment: i don't think viber allow this feature.

Comment: Do you want to back up the messages to Gmail specifically, or just to a Google backup service?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this I've found is if you install Viber on your pc.  A code is sent to your phone that you confirm. That's it.

Comment: How to start the `back-up to Gmail` after installed?

Comment: @NamGVU Could you write more from this?